# How to Pass the source object value and another parameter using value reader in data exchange

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I need to invoke a method in the value mapping to make some logic on the source object before send it to the target but I need to pass another parameter with the source object so I couldn`t use the static method value reader Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate this with more information and also add information how it is related to Sitecore also add any sample code you tried for this,

Comment: I am using data exchange to transfer data from a database to xconnect but I need to make some logic on the data before being transferred to xconnect so I used static method value reader in the mapping but it takes only on parameter which is the source I am asking if there is any way to path the source and another parameter with it to my method

Comment: I think you might need to create custom universal tracker UT as it allows you to take data from different sources then you can process and push to xConnect. Below is th reference link 

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/universal-tracker.html